# Manually Trigger `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` at a Certain Time

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have a `UINavigationController`, containing a `UIViewController` that is parent to two `UITableViewController` controllers.

When the user taps on a segmented control in the `UIToolbar` of the navigation controller, the current child table controller is swapped out with the new one. This includes removing the old controller from the parent hierarchy and removing its view as a subview of the parent view controller.

The first view controller that is displayed when the navigation view controller first presents it has its `contentInset` correctly configured by `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`, however, when I pull that one out and insert the view from the second table view controller, that does not.

Furthermore, if I rotate the device (Which shrinks the `UINavigationBar`) and then swap back to the first view controller, its `contentInset` is now incorrect and it doesn't scroll properly. The second controller, however, does have its `contentInset` property properly set as a result of the device rotation.

Is there a way to manually force a `UIViewController` to redo its `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` operation when I need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an absolutely amazing one, but I found a solution that works.

Inserting a new child view controller isn't enough to trigger `UINavigationController` to automatically work out the appropriate `contentInset` values for any scroll views in the new child. BUT! You can force it to perform that calculation by doing something that would have required it anyway. For example, hiding and showing the navigation bar or toolbar.

```
- (void)insertViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // Add the view to our view
    viewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

    // Add the new controller as a child
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // Show and hide the toolbar to force the content inset calculation
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
}
```

I've tested it, and there appear to be no visual glitches by rapidly hiding either the navigation bar or toolbar, so this solution seems to be acceptable.